# Laravel merge a relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

How can I merge my Laravel code to have only one collection? I have the following

```
$users = User::with(['messages'=> function($query) {
    $query->select('sender');
}])->with(['files' => function($query) {
  $query->select('size');
}])->get(['name']);
```

I expect my results to be

```
[
  {
    "name": "user 1",
    "sender": "user 3",
    "size": "3 MB"
  }
]
```

Comment: use first() instead of get()

Comment: I want a list of users not a single user

Comment: If you loop over your current users collection, do you access the sender by doing `$user->messages->sender`?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote messages and files as plural mean its a OneToMany, mean messages and files should retrieve a collection of object

Anyway if its for an API (as i see you want to return json) you could use the laravel ressources (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources) and prepare your object

```
return [
    'name' => $this->name,
    'sender' => $this->messages->sender,
    'size' => $this->files->size
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `with()` relation, the resultant collection will have the relative collections inside it.

In your case :

```
user_collection
 - userdata
 .
 .
 - file_collection
 - message_collection
```

Now, there are few ways you can do it :

**1. Have a join query :**

```
$users = User::join('messages', 'messaged.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('files', 'files.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('users.name', 'files.size', 'messages.sender')
    ->get();
```

**2. Format data using resources :**

[Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources) are a kind of mapper or modifier which will return the response in format you like. It standardises the response the way you want it.

You can create `app\Http\Resources\UserResource.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class User extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'size' => $this->files->size,
            'sender' => $this->messages->sender,
            'name' => $this->name
        ];
    }
}
```

And then inside controller :

```
return new UserResource(User::find(1));
```

The advantage is  that if you want messages to look certain way, you can nest the Resource classes. The documentation has detailed examples.